# How do you dismiss a notification in iOS?

Tags: ios, push-notification, notificationcenter

I have an iOS app that uses push notifications. I have it set up to take the user to a specific view in my app when they click on one of the notifications in notification center. After the app launches from clicking on that notification and I look back at notification center, the notification is still there. How can I dismiss this notification?

Previous questions have been asked about this, but they have all said that this can not be done. However I can see that several apps (such as the mail app, calendar app, words with friends, etc) are all able to remove specific items from notification center when you interact with them.